# How to group by using bit column?

Tags: sql-server, group-by, max, bit, coalesce

my table data

```
id  quota  
1  0  
1  NULL  
1  1  
2  0  
2  NULL  
3  NULL
```

Result I Except

```
id  quota  
1  1  
2  0  
3  NULL
```

Result I am getting:

```
id  quota  
1  1  
2  0  
3  0
```

Query I am using:

```
 select id,count(id) count_id,
 case when max(coalesce(quota,0)) = 1 then 1
 when max(coalesce(quota,0)) = 0 then 0
 else null 
 end as quota from forbit group by i
```

My data type for column quota is bit.

I want whenever the max in group is 1 give quota as 1, whenever the max in group is 0 give quota as 0 and whenever the max in group is null give quota as null.
I basically want to achieve NULL for id 3.

Similar post I saw:
[Use column of type bit to differentiate group by?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26890655/use-column-of-type-bit-to-differentiate-group-by/62097775#62097775)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think just a simple `max` is what you are looking for, after converting to an `int` because `max` doesn't work on a `bit`.

```
declare @Test table (id int, quota bit);

insert into @Test (id, quota)
values
(1, 0)
, (1, NULL)
, (1, 1)  
, (2, 0) 
, (2, NULL)  
, (3, NULL);

select id, max(convert(int,quota))
from @Test
group by id;
```

Returns:

```
id  quota
1   1
2   0
3   NULL
```

Answer (score -2):

It seems you are over thinking tings, you can do it with simple query as below:

```
select max(cast(quota) as int) as max_val, id
from test
group by id
```

Comment: Adds no value compared with the answer submitted 4 hours ago. Don't post answers which are essentially duplicates of others (use of `cast` vs `convert` is not a meaningful difference)